# Protection... failure?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[Where is a good place to find writing prompts?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/where-is-a-good-place-to-find-writing-prompts/7715#7715)

This post was made to a protected question that mentions that only users with 10+ rep can answer and yet, that new user was able to answer it?

I understand that the user has 10+ on another SE site, but isn't the protection for SE Writers only?

I assumed it was something I should flag here...

I have nothing against the post though, just was surprised by it being posted on that protected thread.

Comment: The answer and the protection both appeared yesterday (timestamps not yet showing).  Perhaps they appeared in that order?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hmm, I didn't notice that protections have a timestamp. You're right, that could be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was posted ***before*** Neil Fein put the protection up. Hence how a 1-rep user was able to answer.